# Ergodicity of stochastic recursive process

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, ergodic-theory, time-series

Does anyone know how one can show ergodicity for a recursive stochastic process determined by the following equation:
\begin{equation}
        X_n = f(\varepsilon_{n-1},Y_{n-1})X_{n-1}, 
\end{equation}
where $(Y_n)_{n>0}$ is a given stationary process $(\varepsilon_n)_{n>0}$ is an i.i.d. sequence, and f isn't specified? Or maybe someone knows good references for the problem?